Why does calculating acceleration of different bodies differently in free body diagram yields the wrong answer?
I was reading the  Fundamental laws of Mechanics by Irodov and encountered a problem [Problem 2.2]

Here I went on to solve by my method:
Net force on the block $m_1$:
$$m_1 g-T$$
Net force on the block $m_2$:
$$m_2 g \sin \alpha - km_2g \cos \alpha -T$$
(First term is force due to gravity ; second is force due to friction; third is tension)
We also know $m_2 = \frac{3}{2} m_1$
Now $F_{m_2}$ is :
$$\left(\frac{3}{2}m_1\right)g \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)- \left(\frac{1}{10}\right) \left(\frac{3}{2}m_1\right)g \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)-T$$
So after all of this:
$F_{m_2} \approx 0.62 m_1 g-T$
Now as the $m_2$ force is acting opposite to $m_1$ we will subtract $m_2$ from $m_1$ to find the final net force on $m_1$ .
So that is [$T$ gets cancelled out]
$m_1g- 0.62m_1 g$
And the final force on m_1 is:
$0.38m_1 g $
And acceleration on $m_1$ [Force divided by mass]:
$$0.38g$$
which is totally different from the textbook answer of $0.05g$
I don't know where I am going wrong??? Can yall help me??
(Im a ninth grader and I must be going wrong somewhere as all of this is self learnt)

and the question is closed, leaving my brilliant answer hanging. I'll outline it: with $m_1=2m$, $m_2=3m$, the total force accelerating $5m$ is $2mg-T$ where $T/mg=(2-3k\cos\alpha)$, boom, done.

First, you are taking acceleration of the two blocks in different directions.
And, second, you are not writing the full equation using Newton's Second law.
If we write the net force in block $m_1$ to be:
$$F_{m_1}=m_1g-T$$
Then, we are considering the block $m_1$ to be moving downward. So it should pull the block $m_2$ upward.
So, the net force on the block $m_2$ should be considered as:
$$F_{m_2}=T-m_2g\sin{\alpha}-km_2g\cos{\alpha}$$
Also, since they are connected by the same string, and string length is not changing with time, so they must have the same acceleration, say $a$.
Using, Newton's Second law: $F_{net}=ma$, we get:
$$F_{m_1}=m_1a \tag{1}$$
$$F_{m_2}=m_2a \tag{2}$$
Now, we have to find $a$ and upon solving $eq(1)$ and $(2)$,we get:
$$a\approx 0.048g$$
Edit:
The $eq(1)$ and $(2)$ are:
$$m_1g-T=m_1a$$
$$T-m_2g\sin{\alpha}-km_2g\cos{\alpha}=m_2a$$
If we add the above equations,we get:
$$m_1g-m_2g\sin{\alpha}-km_2g\cos{\alpha}=(m_1+m_2)a$$
Which implies:
$$\frac{5}{2}a=g-\frac{3}{4}g-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{40}g$$
So,
$$a\approx 0.048g$$

Can you please elaborate the equation part..

@Rutajit45adude See the edit.
